# Type definition with dynamic properties

Tags: typescript

I'm getting data like this:

```json
{
  "_embedded": {
    "Customers": [{ "CompanyName": "AWS" }]
  }
}
```

Another one might look like this:

```json
{
  "_embedded": {
    "Products": [{ "SKU": "ABC123" }]
  }
}
```

So it's always the same structure except for the property name inside `_embedded`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a TypeScript type alias like this:

```js
type MyType<T> = {
  _embedded: {
    Customers: Array<T>
  }
}
```

I can make the type being used in the array generic but I don't know if it's possible to make the name of the property in `_embedded` (`Customer` here) dependent on a string value.

Comment: What do you mean by "dependent on a string value"?

Comment: Sounds like you want `Record<K, V>` where `K` is the property type; or equivalently a mapped type `{[k in K]: V}`.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes something like this but `Record<K, V>` won`t work because `V` is a type and I want to change the name of the property from e.g. `Customers` to `Products`.

Comment: @Luke-zhang-04 I want to change the name of the property which is named `Customers` in the first snippet and `Products` in the second one.

Comment: `'Customers'` and `'Products'` can be string literal types.

Comment: @kaya3 how would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's my solution based on [kaya3's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66700780/type-definition-with-dynamic-properties/66701035#comment117908685_66700780):

```js
type MyType<T, K extends string> = {
  _embedded: Record<K, T>
}
```

It can be used like this:

```js
const x: MyType<Array<Customer>>, 'customers'> = { 
  _embedded: { customers: [] }
}
```